# material-ui and navigation button with component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-router-dom

Following the example at https://material-ui.com/guides/composition/#button, i define in my main page a button:

```
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Box m={2}>
          <Button
            size="large" variant="contained"
            color="primary" endIcon={<TimerIcon />}
            fullWidth={true}
            component={SubmitTime}>
            Enter hours
          </Button>
        </Box>
      </BrowserRouter>
```

Documentation states:

> Routing libraries
> The integration with third-party routing libraries is achieved with the **component** prop. The behavior is identical to the description of the prop above. Here are a few demos with react-router-dom. It covers the Button, Link, and List components, you should be able to apply the same strategy with all the components.

Now, based on the above, my understanding would be that the above would render a button that, when clicked, would get me to the SubmitTime component. Instead, I get the component itself rendered:

[image]

Being new to React and react-router-dom, i think i am doing something wrong, but can't understand what?? Any clue appreciated.

I tried adding 'to' to the component, like so, with same results:

```
        <Button
          size="large" variant="contained"
          color="primary" endIcon={<TimerIcon />}
          fullWidth={true}
          component={SubmitTime} to="/timesheet">
          Enter hours
        </Button>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`component` is supposed to be the style of the button. Here you can see an example of using the button as a link: https://material-ui.com/components/buttons/#cursor-not-allowed. Also try reading the api: https://material-ui.com/api/button/#props
If you want your button to function as a link, add the `href="/timesheet"` attribute to it. Else push the route to the history:

```
const history = useHistory();
...

<Button
  size="large" variant="contained"
  color="primary" endIcon={<TimerIcon />}
  fullWidth={true}
  onClick={() => history.push("/timesheet")}
  >
  Enter hours
</Button>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. what does the sentence "One common use case is to use the button to trigger navigation to a new page. The ButtonBase component provides a property to handle this use case: component" in the documentation right above your link"? Also, href seemingly voids the state of the application, so not really an option for me

Comment: You can also send state with history.push().

Comment: it works with onClick={() => history.push("/timesheet", appState)} thanks!

Comment: Nice, great to hear!